# Where to update entity in Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring-data

I have account, which has many review

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {

@Id
private String username;
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Review> reviews;

public Account(String username, String name) {
    this.username = username;
    this.name = name;
    this.reviews = new ArrayList<>();
}
}
```

Here I have List of reviews, and now I want to implement Service Reviews Layer; so the question arises: where I should add this logic. So far as I can see there are two options:

1. Write set method in Account entity
2. Write update query in Account repository

The first one seems nice, but I'm unsure if it lead to encapsulation violation.
Appreciate any advice on this!

Comment: what do you mean by review layer

Comment: @Icarus I mean Service layer for reviews

Comment: do it in the service layer. You will want the service layer to update the database